# Comparing values in different pairs of columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, calculated-columns

I would like to count how many times column A has the same value with B and with C. Similarly, I would like to count how many time A2 has the same value with B2 and with C2.

I have this dataframe:

```
,A,B,C,A2,B2,C2
2018-12-01,7,0,8,17,17,17
2018-12-02,0,0,8,20,18,18
2018-12-03,9,8,8,17,17,18
2018-12-04,8,8,8,17,17,18
2018-12-05,8,8,8,17,17,17
2018-12-06,9,8,8,15,17,17
2018-12-07,8,9,9,17,17,16
2018-12-08,0,0,0,17,17,17
2018-12-09,8,0,0,17,20,18
2018-12-10,8,8,8,17,17,17
2018-12-11,8,8,9,17,17,17
2018-12-12,8,8,8,17,17,17
2018-12-13,8,8,8,17,17,17
2018-12-14,8,8,8,17,17,17
2018-12-15,9,9,9,17,17,17
2018-12-16,12,0,0,17,19,17
2018-12-17,11,9,9,17,17,17
2018-12-18,8,9,9,17,17,17
2018-12-19,8,9,8,17,17,17
2018-12-20,9,8,8,17,17,17
2018-12-21,9,9,9,17,17,17
2018-12-22,10,9,0,17,17,17
2018-12-23,10,11,10,17,17,17
2018-12-24,10,10,8,17,19,17
2018-12-25,7,10,10,17,17,18
2018-12-26,10,0,10,17,19,17
2018-12-27,9,10,8,18,17,17
2018-12-28,9,9,9,17,17,17
2018-12-29,10,10,12,18,17,17
2018-12-30,10,0,10,16,19,17
2018-12-31,11,8,8,19,17,16
```

I expect the following value:

```
A with B = 14
A with C = 14
A2 with B2 = 14
A2 with C2 = 14
```

I have done this:

```
ia = 0
for i in range(0,len(dfr_h_max1)):
    if dfr_h_max1['A'][i] == dfr_h_max1['B'][i]:
        ia=ia+1
        
ib = 0
for i in range(0,len(dfr_h_max1)):
    if dfr_h_max1['A'][i] == dfr_h_max1['C'][i]:
        ib=ib+1
```

In order to take advantage of pandas, this is one possible solution:

```
import numpy as np
dfr_h_max1['que'] = np.where((dfr_h_max1['A'] == dfr_h_max1['B']), 1, 0)
```

After that I could sum all the elements in the new column 'que'.
Another possibility could be related to some sort of boolean variable. Unfortunately, I still do not have enough knowledge about that.

Any other more efficient or elegant solutions?

Comment: Probably, I have found an elegant solution. Shall I edit the question or delete it or leave it as future warning about what to not do? Thanks and sorry for the rushing in making this question

Comment: @diedro Edit your question showing your current solution. Since you've already edited it to show what you've tried, it may get re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

The primary calculation you need here is, for example, `dfr_h_max1['A'] == dfr_h_max1['B']` - as you've done in your edit. That gives you a Series of `True`/`False` values based on the equality of each pair of items in the two series. Since `True` evaluates to `1` and `False` evaluates to `0`, the `.sum()` is the count of how many `True`'s there were - hence, how many matches.

Put that in a loop and add the required "text" for the output you want:

```py
mains = ('A', 'A2')  # the main columns
comps = (['B', 'C'], ['B2', 'C2'])  # columns to compare each main with

for main, pair in zip(mains, comps):
    for col in pair:
        print(f'{main} with {col} = {(dfr_h_max1[main] == dfr_h_max1[col]).sum()}')
        # or without f-strings, do:
        # print(main, 'with', col, '=', (dfr_h_max1[main] == dfr_h_max1[col]).sum())
```

Output:

```
A with B = 14
A with C = 14
A2 with B2 = 21
A2 with C2 = 20
```

Btw, `(df[main] == df[comp]).sum()` for [`Series.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas.Series.sum) can also be written as `sum(df[main] == df[comp])` for Python's builtin `sum()`.

---

In case you have more than two "triplets" of columns (not just A & A2), change the `mains` and `comps` to this, so that it works on all triplets:

```py
mains = dfr_h_max1.columns[::3]  # main columns (A's), in steps of 3
comps = zip(dfr_h_max1.columns[1::3],  # offset by 1 column (B's),
            dfr_h_max1.columns[2::3])  # offset by 2 columns (C's),
                                       # in steps of 3
```

(Or even using the column names / starting letter.)